# sql - show count of field from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a Milestone table:
[image]

and a Status table:

[image]

I have a query:

```
SELECT T1.Status,T2.MilestoneTitle FROM [Organisation].[dbo].[Status] T1
JOIN [Organisation].[dbo].[Milestone] T2 
ON T1.StatusId=T2.MilestoneStatusId WHERE T2.ProjectId=4
```

which gives output as:

[image]

Now, I want to display Output as:

[image]

How can the query be written for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using Count and Group we can achieve this

```
SELECT 
    T1.Status, COUNT(T2.MilestoneTitle) AS MilestoneTitleCount  
FROM 
    [Organisation].[dbo].[Status] T1
JOIN 
    [Organisation].[dbo].[Milestone] T2 ON T1.StatusId  = T2.MilestoneStatusId 
WHERE 
    T2.ProjectId = 4
GROUP BY 
    T1.Status
ORDER BY   
    T1.Status DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Status, COUNT(MilestoneTitle) AS MilestoneTitleCount
FROM Organisation.dbo.Status  INNER JOIN
Organisation.dbo.Milestone  ON StatusId = MilestoneStatusId
WHERE (ProjectId = 4)
GROUP BY Status
```

The `COUNT()` function returns the number of rows that **matches a specified criteria**.

```
SELECT COUNT(column_name) FROM table_name;
```

The `GROUP BY` statement is used in conjunction with the **aggregate functions** to group the result-set by one or more columns.

```
SELECT column_name, Count(column_name)
FROM table_name
WHERE <Confidtion>
GROUP BY column_name;
```